# Making browsers ignore the URL hash when the back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if an user is on http://example.com, then the user goes to http://example.com#comments. If the user clicks "back" on his browser, how can I make him "ignore" http://example.com and go directly to the URL that he visited before that?

I have jQuery loaded.

Comment: You'd have to block the click that got him to `#comments` in the first place, perhaps using a `preventDefault()` and use jQuery to scroll there instead.  Otherwise, it all becomes part of the normal history.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of having a link like:

```
<a href='#comments'>Link</a>
```

Use `location.replace()` to "overwrite" the record of `http://example.com` in the browser's history.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

**Example:**

HTML:

```
<a id='commentsLink'>Link</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#commentsLink").click(function(){
    window.location.replace("#comments");
});
```

Comment: Don't use w3schools... http://w3fools.com (Alternative link for info on `window.location`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: @Platinum Azure - That was in the back of my mind when I posted the link, but laziness got the best of me. Thanks for setting me straight :)

Comment: Thanks for actually fixing it. +1 for your trouble :-)

Comment: "you win this time" :), I would try to change my vote as soon as I am able (in case I am, I really don't know entirely how SO works). Sorry to have deleted my prev comments, but I don't want to lower the IQ of the ppl reading this with my nonsenses...

Comment: :). You can just click upvote and it will undo the downvote, unless SO has decided to lock in the vote (which it does after a certain period of time).

Comment: @SimpleCoder it is impossible now... it is locked until you edit