# remove hash location from history and browsers back button

Tags: javascript

i have a project in which i have to scroll to a particular image out of a list of them. those images are lazy loaded (since they are all high resolution).

my current approach is to have an internal link to each one of them:

```
<a name="photo1"><img ... /></a>
```

when i click on a thumbnail to see the original photo i get a click by doing:

```
location.hash = "#photo1"
```

the problem is when i click browser back and forward, the page does not go back to the prev page, instead goes back to whatever photo link has been clicked previously

how can i remove all hash from history?

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet here, I think, is to manually scroll to a target element with JavaScript.

Use the native `scrollIntoView` to jump to your element:

```
document.getElementById('[id]').scrollIntoView(true);
```

You can actually execute this in the `<a>` `href` attribute.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('[id]').scrollIntoView(true);">
```

Then, if you desire, you can manually add in the hash without adding a new history entry.

```
window.location.replace("#[id]");
```

Sources:

[Making browsers ignore the URL hash when the back button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146481/making-browsers-ignore-the-url-hash-when-the-back-button-is-clicked)

[Scroll with anchor without # in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223006/scroll-with-anchor-without-in-urlscro)

[How to call JavaScript function instead of href in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003867/how-to-call-javascript-function-instead-of-href-in-html)

Comment: this solution is not working for me because all images are lazy loaded and with different sizes, once an image is loaded and is taller than the min height, the selected thumbnail goes out of the view

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Just to be clear, `[id]` in your examples is intended to be replacement text? Making the actual invocation something like `<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('toc1').scrollIntoView(true);">`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So, in the original example, we'd use `document.getElementById('photo1')`.